# how to check first 3 or 4 elements are true in nodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
   time : [
  true, true,  true,
  true, true,  true,
  true, false, false
]
```

this is an array I'm getting, I want to find with if condition whether first for elements are true or not?

Comment: `if(time[0] && time[1] && time[2] && time[3])` …?

Comment: If you want to use just an `if` statement, you can simply do `if (time[0] && time[1] && time[2] && time[3]) { ... }`; as soon as one of them is `false`, the entire condition is `false`

Answer (score 0):

Just slice and check then. (you can use [`Array.prototype.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) for the checking)

```js
const time = [
  true, true, true,
  true, true, true,
  true, false, false
]

console.log(time.slice(0, 4).every(item => item))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a really simple task using the `slice` and `includes` method. First slice the list, then check to see if it includes any false values.

```js
let firstFourAreTrue = !time
  .slice(0, 4)
  .includes(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the description of the question `time` I think it is an object.

This code returns values for 3 and 4. The values are set in an array and other values can be added.

```js
var t = {
    time: [
        true, true, true,
        true, true, true,
        true, false, false
    ]
};

var p = [3, 4];

p.forEach(i => {
    var ret = t.time.slice(0, i).every(x => x);
    console.log('First',i, ret);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution without slicing.

```js
const check = array => array.every((v, i) => i >= 4 || v);

console.log(check([true, true, true, true, true, true, true, false, false]));
console.log(check([false, true, true, true, true, true, true, false, false]));
console.log(check([true, false, true, true, true, true, true, false, false]));
console.log(check([true, true, false, true, true, true, true, false, false]));
console.log(check([true, true, true, false, true, true, true, false, false]));
```